# Getting an Arduino function to loop within a switch case

Tags: arduino

I'm trying to get the function `flash()` to repeat, but it stops when `clickevent()` occurs again and case 0 becomes active.

I think my error is that case 0 is not becoming active because it's stuck on case 1 maybe? I can get it to start using `while()` statements or `do while()` statements but then I can't exit the loop, any help would be very appreciated.

```cpp
// ======== change the lighting mode setting between flash and solid with a single click of the button ===========
int ModeSetting = 0;
void clickEvent()
{
    Serial.println("Click Occured");
    ModeSetting++;
    if (ModeSetting > 1)
        ModeSetting = 0;
    ChangeMode(ModeSetting);
}

void ChangeMode(int i)
{
    switch (i)
    {
    case 0:
        strip.setBrightness(255);
        Serial.println("MODE = SOLID COLOUR"); // SOLID LIGHT;
        break;
    case 1:
        flash(); // THE FUNCTION THAT NEEDS TO LOOP pls help

        break;
    }
}

int flashstate = LOW;
unsigned long PrevFlashMillis = 0;
const long flashinterval = 1000;
void flash()
{
    unsigned long currentFlashMillis = millis();
    if (currentFlashMillis - PrevFlashMillis >= flashinterval)
    {
        // save the last time you blinked the LED
        PrevFlashMillis = currentFlashMillis;
        // if the LED is off turn it on and vice-versa:
        if (flashstate == LOW)
        {
            strip.setBrightness(255);
            Serial.println("FLASH ON");
            flashstate == HIGH;
        }
        else
        {
            strip.setBrightness(0);
            Serial.println("FLASH OFF");
            flashstate == LOW;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the `void loop()` in your code snippet. I suspect the best place to make the change will be in there.

Comment: anyway, you CAN exit the loop: just use the 'break;' when necessary:
    'if( I_WANT_EXIT)
       break;'